# Updating jQuery to the latest version in an ASP.NET MVC 3 application

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to update the version of jQuery used by an ASP.NET MVC 3 application?

If so, is it a matter of simply replacing the jquery-1.4.4.js and jquery-1.4.4.min.js files with the latest ones (currently version 1.5) and it all just works?

Or are there links between the version shipped with ASP.NET MVC 3 and other JavaScript code which would then break?

What about jQuery UI, same story?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always download and update your jQuery via http://www.jquery.com.

Unless they change some functionality you're using you should be able to update it just fine.

Same with jQuery UI I suspect

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have any third party JQuery plugin scripts, then you should be just fine.

If you do use any plugins, check the author's site for any updates.  The author may already know if there are any issues with the latest JQuery version.